# ArrayBlockingQueue in which queue head is removed if the queue is full while adding an element

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to write a simple queue like ArrayBlockingQueue in which the head of the queue will be removed if the queue is full while adding an element. The class should just have the below public methods

- To get the size of the Queue
- To get an element from the head of the queue
- To add an element at the tail of the queue

Can someone review the below code and let me know if there is a better way of doing this?

```
public class CircularArrayNonBlockingQueue<E> {
    private ArrayBlockingQueue<E> blockingQueue;

    public CircularArrayNonBlockingQueue(int size) {
        blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(size);
    }

    public synchronized int size() {
        return blockingQueue.size();
    }

    public synchronized void add(E element) {
        if(blockingQueue.remainingCapacity() <= 0) {
            blockingQueue.poll();
        }
        blockingQueue.add(element);
    }

    public synchronized E poll() {
        return blockingQueue.poll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to use EvictingQueue from Google guava?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25059883/3314834

Comment: I am planning to use this in a producer consumer type pattern in which consumer will be blocked till a new element is available but the producer will never be blocked , if there is no space then head will be removed to have space for new element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871092/arrayblockingqueue-in-which-queue-head-is-removed-if-the-queue-is-full-while-add)

> Having a thread-safe backend collection does not necessarily make a
>   correct program. When only your `add` method is `synchronized`, the
>   `take()` method may run concurrently to it, so it is possible that
>   after your `if(blockingQueue.remainingCapacity() <= 0)` test within
>   `add`, a concurrently running `take()` removes an element, so the
>   `poll()` within `add` may remove an element unnecessarily. There is a
>   perceivable difference to the situation where `add()` would complete
>   before the `take()`, as the consuming thread would receive a different
>   item. It other words, the effect would be as if `add` would sometimes
>   not remove the oldest item, but the second oldest one.
>
> On the other hand, if you use `synchronized` for all of your methods
>   consistently, there is no need to have a thread-safe backend
>   collection:
>
> ```
> import java.util.ArrayDeque;
>
> public class CircularNonBlockingQueue<E> {
>     private final ArrayDeque<E> blockingQueue;
>     private final int maxSize;
>
>     public CircularNonBlockingQueue(int size) {
>         if(size<1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("size == "+size);
>         blockingQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(size);
>         maxSize = size;
>     }
>
>     public synchronized int size() {
>         return blockingQueue.size();
>     }
>
>     public synchronized void add(E element) {
>         if(blockingQueue.size() == maxSize) {
>             blockingQueue.poll();
>         }
>         blockingQueue.add(element);
>         notify();
>     }
>
>     public synchronized E take() throws InterruptedException {
>         while(blockingQueue.isEmpty()) wait();
>         return blockingQueue.remove();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> However, if you can live with weaker guarantees regarding the oldest
>   element, you can use a `BlockingQueue` and don’t need any
>   `synchronized`:
>
> ```
> public class CircularNonBlockingQueue<E> {
>     private final ArrayBlockingQueue<E> blockingQueue;
>
>     public CircularNonBlockingQueue(int size) {
>         blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(size);
>     }
>
>     public int size() {
>         return blockingQueue.size();
>     }
>
>     public void add(E element) {
>         while(!blockingQueue.offer(element)) {
>             blockingQueue.poll();
>         }
>     }
>
>     public E take() throws InterruptedException {
>         return blockingQueue.take();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> It must be noted that neither of these solutions provides “fairness”.
>   So if the number of producer and consumer threads is large compared to
>   the queue’s capacity, there is the risk that producers repeatedly
>   remove items without reactivating threads blocked in `take()`. So you
>   should always ensure to have a sufficiently large capacity.